# Dynamically creating multidimensional inline keyboard telegram bot api?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

My Code:

```
var keyBoardData = [];
var menu = ['Nightclub', 'Parks'];
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  keyBoardData.push([{'text': menu[i], 'callback_data': '{"a":(menu[i]),"b":(menu[i])}' }]);
}
var keyBoard = {"inline_keyboard": keyBoardData};
```

result is:

```
{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Nightclub","callback_data":"{\"a\":(menu[i]),\"b\":(menu[i])}"}],
[{"text":"Parks","callback_data":"{\"a\":(menu[i]),\"b\":(menu[i])}"}]]}
```

but am trying to get:

```
{"inline_keyboard":[[{"text":"Nightclub","callback_data":'{"a":"Nightclub","b":"Nightclub"}'}],
[{"text":"Parks","callback_data":'{"a":"Parks","b":"Parks"}'}]]}
```

working with telegram bot api and google sheets app script.
need to display a column data as Buttons in telegram and on selection of button needs to filter sheets data using callback_data and return the result.

am having issue here: '{"a":(menu[i]),"b":(menu[i])}' this fits inline keyboard but menu[i]) treating as text.
if i remove single quotes am able to get data but inline keyboard not works.

any suggestion.

Comment: In your case, when you want to use the value of `'{"a":(menu[i]),"b":(menu[i])}'` including the variables as the string, I thought that you can modify `keyBoardData.push([{'text': menu[i], 'callback_data': '{"a":(menu[i]),"b":(menu[i])}' }]);` to `keyBoardData.push([{'text': menu[i], 'callback_data': JSON.stringify({"a":menu[i],"b":menu[i]})}]);`. But I cannot understand about `but inline keyboard not works.`. Can I ask you about the detail of your issue?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** create [json](/questions/tagged/json) by hard-coding strings.

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) and [`URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) to format the required data;

An example, using the same data; with the result below;

```js
// Create keyBoard data
var keyBoardData = [];
var menu = ['Nightclub', 'Parks'];
for (var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++) {
  keyBoardData.push({
      text: menu[i],
      callback_data: menu[i]
  });
}

// Create fetch options
var requestOptions = new URLSearchParams({
  reply_markup: JSON.stringify({ "inline_keyboard": [ keyBoardData ]}),
  chat_id: 12345678,
  text: 'Test Keyboard'
}).toString();

// Send test
const token = '1134534202?????????????';
fetch("https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token + "/sendMessage?" + requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

[image]