# problem on check who button clicked in google script for telegram bot

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

problem on check who button clicked in google script for telegram bot

Hello
I have tested many codes all over the internet but I have not succeeded in solving my problem
I wrote a bot for Telegram with google script
I defined two keys with inline_keyboard
Define a code for each key according to the user's information, but I did not succeed
I put the code
please help

```
var KEYBOARD_MAIN = {
  "inline_keyboard": [
    [{ "text": "button 1", 'callback_data': 'btn1' }],
    [{ "text": "button 2", 'callback_data': 'btn2' }]
  ]
};
```

and this code for doPost()

```
function doPost(e) {
  var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);

  if (contents.callback_query) {


    var data = contents.callback_query.data;
    var chat_id = contents.callback_query.from.id;

    if (data == 'btn1') {
      sendMessage(chat_id, 'btn1 clicked');

    } else if (data == 'btn2') {
      sendMessage(chat_id, 'btn2 clicked');
    }

  } else if (contents.message) {
    var chat_id = contents.message.from.id;
    var text = contents.message.text;


    var contents = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
    var chat_id = contents.message.chat.id;


    if (text == "/start") {
      deleteMessage(chat_id, contents.message.message_id)
      sendMessageKeyboard(chat_id, "enter your command", KEYBOARD_MAIN);

    } else if (!isNaN(parseFloat(text)) && isFinite(text)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < logins.length; i++) {
        if (chat_id == logins[i]) {
          sBot.getRange("C" + (i + 2)).setValue(text);
          replaceKeyBoard(chat_id, sBot.getRange("D" + (i + 2)).getValue());
        }
      }
    }


  }
};
```

Comment: how is `doPost`  called, and what is the `e` argument passed to it?

Comment: This is the complete code
I deleted the part for checking callback_query, because it was not checked
Is this workable?

Comment: so, how is `doPost` called?

Comment: this is my full code

Comment: Please give me a sample code , thanks

Comment: try this is code but get error "ReferenceError: URLSearchParams is not defined"    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656287/dynamically-creating-multidimensional-inline-keyboard-telegram-bot-api?rq=2